# Помогите разобраться с построением интерфейса Java

Tags: java

[image: Интерфейс]

У моей программы вот такой интерфейс. Подскажите как сделать , что б при нажатии на кнопку , в области , которая черным цветом , открывалась та JPanel , которая предназначена для этой кнопки

Comment: вешайте на кнопку actionListener и в нем делайте то, что вам нужно

Comment: Ну это я понимаю , так и делаю . Но как сделать , что б одна Панель удалялась , а другая создавалась

Comment: удаляйте одну и создавайте другую, делов то.

Comment: Спасибо большое , наконец то разобрался ) Логика у меня была правильная , но реализация неправильная) Спасибо , что помогли